# Smooth function that is almost constant over a range becomes linear?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I want a function $f(x)$ such that given an interval $[a,b]$ $f'(x) \approx 0+$ and then if $x \geq b$ $f'(x) \approx 1$

i.e. the function is mostly constant (and ideally equal to one) and then it smoothly and quickly transitions to being linear with a slope of 1.

A similar function I was able to make was $e^{x - b} + 1$ this one has 2 issues, first it only works if $a=0$ and second it is an exponential rather than a linear growth.

Comment: You could consider a mollification of the ReLU function.

Comment: Just come up with a derivative and integrate it. A hyperbolic tangent should work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed function is exponential, hence one possible proposal that I can think of is to take logarithm of your function.

Consider the function

$$f(x) = 1+\log(\exp(x-b)+1)$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{\exp(x-b)}{\exp(x-b)+1}=\frac{1}{1+\exp(b-x)}$$ which converges to $1$ when $x\to \infty$.

[image]